# datewise searching not working in pagination

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My search result correctly displaying. But when I click the second page or pagination then all the data is displaying

**my view - date selecting**

Here I select the date using the date picker

```
<div class='floatl modal-form col-sm-12'>
<div class='col-sm-5'>
<input type='text' class='dateTablePicker' readonly id='dateTableFrom' 
placeholder='date from'/>
</div>
<div class='col-sm-5'>
<input type='text' class='dateTablePicker' readonly id='dateTableTo' 
placeholder='date to'/>
</div>
<div class='col-sm-2'>
<button class='btn-success' onclick="filterTable()"> Filter</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class='contentTable'>
<?php

$this->load->view("pages/tableData/leads_data");

?>
</div>


<script>
$(function () {
    $(".dateTablePicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});

function filterTable() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?= site_url('OperationRouter/filterTableData'); ?>",
        data: {dateTableFrom: $('#dateTableFrom').val(), dateTableTo: $('#dateTableTo').val()},


        success: function (data) {


            $(".contentTable").html(data);

        }
    });
}
```

**leads_data//table data listing**

The data displaying if the `datefrom` and `dateto` is `isset` then data displaying based on searching.

```
<?php


if (!isset($_SESSION['dateTableFrom'])) $_SESSION['dateTableFrom'] = '';
if (!isset($_SESSION['dateTableTo'])) $_SESSION['dateTableTo'] = '';
$dateTableFrom = $_SESSION['dateTableFrom'];
$dateTableTo = $_SESSION['dateTableTo'];



$page='leads';
$slno = 0;

// CONDITION QUERY
if (isset($_SESSION['export_Sql']))
$cql = $_SESSION['export_Sql'];
else if($dateTableFrom) {
$cql = '
                select leads.id,leads.created,leads.product_id,
                leads.company_id,leads.owner_id,leads.creator_id,
                leads.title,leads.date,products.title as product,
                leads.converted_flag,leads.status,
                companies.title as company,admin.username 
                from admin admin,products products,leads leads,companies 
                companies 
                where products.id=leads.product_id 
                and companies.id=leads.company_id 
                and admin.id=leads.owner_id 
                and leads.remove_status = 1 
                and 
                ( leads.creator_id = ' . $this->session- 
               >userdata['logged_admin'] . ' 
                or FIND_IN_SET(leads.creator_id, ( select 
                GROUP_CONCAT(id) from admin 
                    where parent_id =' . $this->session- 
               >userdata['logged_admin'] . ' )) 
                )
  and STR_TO_DATE(leads.created,"%d-%m-%Y")  >= "' . $dateTableFrom . '" 
  and 
  STR_TO_DATE(leads.created,"%d-%m-%Y") <= "' . $dateTableTo . '"               
                ';
  }
  else
     {
      $cql = '
                select leads.id,leads.created,leads.product_id,
                leads.company_id,leads.owner_id,leads.creator_id,
                leads.title,leads.date,products.title as product,
                leads.converted_flag,leads.status,
                companies.title as company,admin.username 
                from admin admin,products products,leads leads,companies 
                companies 
                where products.id=leads.product_id 
                and companies.id=leads.company_id 
                and admin.id=leads.owner_id 
                and leads.remove_status = 1 
                and 
                ( leads.creator_id = ' . $this->session- 
      >userdata['logged_admin'] . ' 
                or FIND_IN_SET(leads.creator_id, ( select 
      GROUP_CONCAT(id) from admin 
                    where parent_id =' . $this->session- 
         >userdata['logged_admin'] . ' )) 
                )


                ';
       }
        if (isset($_SESSION['export_Ids']) && $_SESSION['export_Ids']) {
         $cql .= " and leads.id in (" . $_SESSION['export_Ids'] . ") ";
        }
         if (isset($_SESSION['export_Order']) && 
     $_SESSION['export_Order'])
  $oql = $_SESSION['export_Order'];
   else
   $oql = ''; // ORDER QUERY

if (isset($_SESSION['export_Limit']))
$lql = $_SESSION['export_Limit'];
 else
 $lql='';

if (isset($_SESSION['export_Ids']) && $_SESSION['export_Ids']) // IF ID'S 
THEN NO EXPORT LIMIT NEEDED
$lql = '';
$sql = $cql . $oql;
$itemcount = $this->OperationModel->getRowCount($sql);
$sql = $cql . $oql . $lql;
?>
<input type='hidden' id='selectedSql' value='<?= $cql ?>'/>
<input type='hidden' id='selectedOrder' value='<?= $oql ?>'/>
<input type='hidden' id='selectedLimit' value='<?= $lql ?>'/>
<?php


$slno = 0;
//$sql='select * from admin_types where remove_status = 1';
$tableArray['searchFields'] = 'leads.title';
$itemsperpage = 6;

$result = $this->OperationModel->getTableData($sql, 
$tableArray['searchFields'], $itemsperpage);


if (isset($result['data'])) {
$admin_det = $this->Adminuser->getsingleadmin($this->session- 
>userdata['logged_admin']);

?>
<div class='custom-data-table '>
    <table class='customtable'>
        <tr>
            <th style='width:70px;' class='checker'>
                <input type='checkbox' class='thCheckbox'/>
                <div class='customCheckbox'></div>
            </th>
            <th style='width:60px;'> No</th>
            <th style='width:230px;'>
                Title
                <div class='floatr'><i class='i-sorter icon-shuffle' 
        data='leads.title'
                                       title='sort records by title'></i> 
       </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                Date
                <div class='floatr'><i class='i-sorter icon-shuffle' 
       data='leads.created'
                                       title='sort records by date '></i> 
       </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                Service
                <div class='floatr'><i class='i-sorter icon-shuffle' 
  data='products.title'
                                       title='sort records by date '></i> 
  </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                Client
                <div class='floatr'><i class='i-sorter icon-shuffle' 
  data='companies.title'
                                       title='sort records by company'> 
        </i></div>
            </th>

            <th>
                Owner
                <div class='floatr'><i class='i-sorter icon-shuffle' 
 data='admin.username'
                                       title='sort records by owner'></i></div>
            </th>
            <?php if ($page != 'excelexport') { ?>
                <?php if ($admin_det[0]['user_type'] == 'admin' || 
 $admin_det[0]['user_type'] == 2) { ?>
                    <th> Conversion
                        <div class='floatr'><i class='i-sorter icon- 
shuffle' data='leads.converted_flag'
                                               title='sort records by 
 conversion status'></i></div>
                    </th>
                <?php } ?>
                <!--
                <th>
                     Status
                </th>
                !-->

                <th> Actions</th>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>

        <?php

   //                                       $slno=intval($current_page);
         if (isset($searchkey)) $searchkey = $searchkey; else $searchkey 
    = '**';
        foreach ($result['data'] as $row) {

            $slno++;
            ?>
            <tr id='<?= $row['id'] ?>'>
                <td>
                    <input type='checkbox' class='tdCheckbox'/>
                    <div id='<?= $row['id'] ?>' class='customCheckbox'> 
        </div>
                </td>
                <td> <?= $slno ?> </td>
                <td><?= $this->OperationModel- 
   >searchKeyCheck($row['title'], $searchkey) ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['created'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $this->OperationModel- 
   >searchKeyCheck($row['product'], $searchkey) ?></td>
                <td><?= $this->OperationModel- 
     >searchKeyCheck($row['company'], $searchkey) ?></td>
                <td><?= $this->OperationModel- 
        >searchKeyCheck($row['username'], $searchkey) ?></td>
                <!--
                                <td><?= $row['lead_status'] ? '<span 
     style="color:green">Active</span>' : '<span 
   style="color:orange">Inactive</span>' ?></td>
                                !-->
                <?php if ($page != 'excelexport') { ?>
                    <?php if ($admin_det[0]['user_type'] == 'admin' || 
          $admin_det[0]['user_type'] == 2) { ?>


                        <td>
                            <button class='status-button'
                                    data-trigger='leads'
                                    data-value='<?= 
      $row['converted_flag'] ?>'
                                    data-raw='<?= $row['id'] ?>'
                                    data-field='converted_flag'
                                    data-success="<span 
     class='colorange'>DisConvert</span>"
                                    data-failure="<span 
     class='colgreen'>Convert</span>">
                                <?= ($row['converted_flag'] == 1) ? " 
   <span class='colorange'>DisConvert</span>" : "<span 
       class='colgreen'>Convert</span>" ?>
                            </button>
                        </td>

                    <?php } ?>

                    <td>
                        <?php

                        if ($row['creator_id'] == 
        $_SESSION['logged_admin'] || $admin_det[0]['user_type'] == 
        'admin' || $admin_det[0]['user_type'] == 2) { ?>

                            <a class='modal-switch'
                               data-toggle='modal'
                               data-target='#getAppUsers'
                               data-ajax='createmeeting'>
                                <i class='fa fa-plus add-bt'></i>
                                Meeting
                            </a>
                            <a class='modal-switch'
                               data-toggle='modal'
                               data-target='#getAppUsers'
                               data-ajax='createlead' data-raw='<?= 
     $row['id'] ?>'>
                                <i class='fa fa-pencil ed-bt'></i>
                            </a>
                            <?php if ($admin_det[0]['user_type'] == 
       'admin') { ?>
                                <a class='delete-trigger' data- 
        trigger='leads' data-raw='<?= $row['id'] ?>'>
                                    <i class='fa fa-trash del-bt'></i>
                                </a>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <a class='modal-switch'
                           data-toggle='modal'
                           data-operation='view'
                           data-target='#getAppUsers'
                           data-ajax='createlead' data-raw='<?= 
          $row['id'] ?>'>
                            <i class='fa fa-eye ed-bt'></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </table>

</div>
<?php

/* THE PAGINATION PART */
$pagination['base_url'] = $page;
$pagination['itemsperpage'] = $itemsperpage;
$pagination['total_rows'] = $this->OperationModel->getRowCount($sql, 
     $tableArray['searchFields']);
/* THE PAGINATION PART */
if (isset($pagination))
    echo $this->OperationModel->getPagination($pagination);
?>
<?php

       } else {
echo " <span class='floatl no-match-span'> <i class='icon-magnifier'></i> 
      <span>Oopz , No data found in database for the corresponding item . 
      </span>  </span> ";
     }

      ?>

        <?php
         $this->session->unset_userdata('dateTableFrom');
          ?>
```

**pagination part**

Here is the pagination part

```
function getPagination($dataArray = '')
{
    $msg = '';
    if ($dataArray) {
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . $dataArray['base_url'];
        //$config['base_url'] = base_url('controller_name/search');
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
        $config['total_rows'] = $dataArray['total_rows'];
        $config['per_page'] = $dataArray['itemsperpage'];
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $msg .= "<div class='pagination'>";
        $msg .= $this->pagination->create_links();
        $msg .= "</div>";
        return $msg;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the search params (filters)  along with the ajax request. (along with the pagination)